# Acknowledge others code in comments

Tags: javadoc

I am reusing some piece of code in my Java class which was taken from other sites or borrow from some other developer with their permission. So I like to acknowledge those people in my Javadoc. Is there any pre-defined tag to be used in Javadoc or can anyone give example on how to acknowledge in Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Oracle Java Documentation guide line

**@author (reference page)**
You can provide one @author tag, multiple @author tags, or no @author tags. In these days of the community process when development of new APIs is an open, joint effort, the JSR can be consider the author for new packages at the package level. For example, the new package java.nio has "@author JSR-51 Expert Group" at the package level. Then individual programmers can be assigned to @author at the class level. As this tag can only be applied at the overview, package and class level, the tag applies only to those who make significant contributions to the design or implementation, and so would not ordinarily include technical writers.